# Create new instance after crash

Tags: android

I have problem when my application crash in my "D-Activity".

> MainActivity -> A Activity -> B-Activity -> C-Activity -> D-Activity

I create instance GlobalClass in MainActivity.

```
public static synchronized GlobalClass getInstance()
{
    if(instance==null)
    {
        instance=new GlobalClass();         
    }
    return instance;
}
```

For instance:
My app crashes in "D Activity". Android restart my app from B Activity but I lost my data in GlobalClass. There were a lot of fields String and ArrayList. How do I get them back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your `GlobalClass` instance to `JSON` using `Gson` library for example. After `GlobalClass` is first time instantiated you can save it's `JSON` representation to the `SharedPreferences` and each time you need it if it is null you can try to read it from `SharedPreferences`.

Example of saving to SharedPreferences:

```
/**
 * @return This session's config data.
 */
public Config getConfig() {
    Config config = new Gson().fromJson(mPreferences.getString(KEY_CONFIG, null), Config.class);
    return config;
}

/**
 * Save this session's config data.
 * 
 * @param config
 *            Config data.
 */
public void setConfig(Config config) {
    mPreferences.edit().putString(KEY_CONFIG, new Gson().toJson(config)).commit();
}
```

Example of getting/setting global value:

```
/**
 * @return Application configuration parameters.
 */
public static Config getConfig() {
    if (sConfig == null)
        sConfig = sPreferences.getConfig();
    return sConfig;
}

/**
 * Set application configuration parameters.
 * 
 * @param config
 *            Config to set.
 */
public static void setConfig(Config config) {
    sPreferences.setConfig(config);
    sConfig = config;
}
```